# Get the sum of powers of 2 for a given number + c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a table with different codes. And their Id's are powers of 2.  (2<sup>0</sup>,  2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup>...).
Based on different conditions my application will assign a value to the "Status" variable.
 for ex :

Status = 272 ( which is 2<sup>8</sup>+ 2<sup>4</sup>)
          Status = 21  ( Which is 2<sup>4</sup>+ 2<sup>2</sup>+2<sup>0</sup>)

If Status = 21 then my method (C#) should tell me that 21 is sum of 16 + 4 + 1.

Comment: So what, you want us to write your code for you?

Comment: So in short the given number have to be spliteted in <=3 numbers ?

Comment: You can use `<sup></sup>` tags for superscripts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for (uint currentPow = 1; currentPow != 0; currentPow <<= 1)
{
   if ((currentPow & QStatus) != 0)
      Console.WriteLine(currentPow); //or save or print some other way
}
```

for `QStatus == 21` it will give

```
1 
4
16
```

***Explanation:***
A power of 2 has exactly one `1` in its binary representation. We take that one to be the rightmost one(least significant) and iteratively push it leftwards(towards more significant) until the number overflows and becomes `0`. Each time we check that `currentPow & QStatus` is not 0.

Answer (score 18):

You can test all bits in the input value if they are checked:

```
int value = 21;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    int mask = 1 << i;
    if ((value & mask) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mask);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
4
16
```

Answer (score 5):

This can probably be done much cleaner with an enum with the `[Flags]` attribute set.

Comment: ... And this gets my vote for "funniest answer of the day".  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is basically binary (because binary is also base 2). You can bitshift values around !

```
uint i = 87;

uint mask;
for (short j = 0; j < sizeof(uint); j++)
{
    mask = 1 << j;
    if (i & mask == 1)
        // 2^j is a factor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise operators for this (assuming that you have few enough codes that the values stay in an integer variable).

`a & (a - 1)` gives you back `a` after unsetting the last set bit.  You can use that to get the value of the corresponding flag, like:

```
while (QStatus) {
  uint nxtStatus = QStatus & (QStatus - 1);

  processFlag(QStatus ^ nxtStatus);

  QStatus = nxtStatus;
  }
```

`processFlag` will be called with the set values in increasing order (e.g. 1, 4, 16 if `QStatus` is originally 21).